# How to disable Enable connection to IoT Hub?

Tags: java, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I am rehistering succesfully a device in a Azure IoT hub via device provisioning service, but i want to disable the property

> Enable connection to IoT Hub

to disable for every registered device.

Is there any way to do this from the code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are plenty of libraries available in different different languages.

I am using RegistryManager class of C#. Here's [a link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.registrymanager?view=azure-dotnet)!.
Let me share C# code which I am using for same,

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices;

public static class EnableDevice
{
    static RegistryManager registryManager;
    static string iotHubConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("iotHubConnectionString");

    [FunctionName("EnableDevice")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        JObject response = new JObject();
        try
        {
            string deviceId = req.Query["device_id"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(deviceId))
            {
                response.Add("message", "Please provide valid device_id in request params or in the request body");
                response.Add("code", 400);
                return new BadRequestObjectResult(response);
            }

            registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(iotHubConnectionString);
            Device device = await registryManager.GetDeviceAsync(deviceId);
            if (device == null)
            {
                response.Add("message", $"Error while enabling device: Device with {deviceId} not found.");
                response.Add("code", 400);
                return new BadRequestObjectResult(response);
            }
            device.Status = DeviceStatus.Enabled;  // DeviceStatus.Disabled to Disable device
            await registryManager.UpdateDeviceAsync(device);

            response.Add("message", "Device enabled successfully");
            response.Add("code", 200);
            return new OkObjectResult(response);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            response.Add("message", e.Message);
            response.Add("stacktrace", e.StackTrace);
            response.Add("code", 500);
            return new BadRequestObjectResult(response);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the REST API that allows to create or update enrollments (either [group enrollments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iot-dps/createorupdateenrollmentgroup/createorupdateenrollmentgroup) or [single enrollments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iot-dps/createorupdateindividualenrollment/createorupdateindividualenrollment)), in particular the `provisioningStatus` flag. (there is a similar API for individual enrollments).
Next time your device tries to use DPS to get its provisioning info, it will be denied access. If you're caching the IoT Hub credentials, you will need to use the [IoT Hub REST API to disable the device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/registrymanager/createorupdatedevice) (see `status` flag) that DPS provisioned in the registry.